# Cannot set folder to be ignored by SVN in Maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn

I have classic maven project structure:

```
src
   |__main
      |___java
      |____resources
             |_____abc
                     |__generated
   |__test
|__svn_test
```

In `resources` folder, I have a script which generates some stuff into `abc/generated` dir which should not be included in SVN repository (I know this is not the ideal setup but I don't intended changing it for now). The problem is, that when I set `svn:ignore` on `src/main/resources/abc/generated` it is not ignored. I tried it setting on `src` dir as a whole and it did not work either. However when I set it on `svn_test` directory it worked as it should.

The project is in Eclipse and project meta files are generated using mvn pax/eclipse plugin.

What am I missing here? What else needs to be done? Is there some additional setting which overrides `svn:ignore`?

Answer (score 1):

You should set svn:ignore property on abc folder with value __generated.

For svn 1.8 also can be used svn:global-ignores on src folder.

Also, please note, that if __generated already added to Subversion, then ignore will not work as usually expected. Ignore works only for 'unversioned' items.